# how to convert an array of object in C# that has different types

Tags: c#, arrays, matlab

How to convert an array of objects to double or any other type?

This is the return answer I get from the Matlab which I turn it to `object[]`      (I used Matlab production server).

This is how it looks like:

```
object[] result = {{double[20, 20]}, ...result[2] ...}
```

Output:

> result[0] is double [,]
>   result[1] is {double[20]}
>   result[2] is {double[20]}
>   result[3] is {byte[525, 700, 3]} //this should be changed to an image
>   later

Comment: Check type of your each object in loop iteration, and cast it there.

Comment: The is better asked at the Matlab support.  There are matlab arrays and c# arrays and they are not always compatible.  You may need a matlab interface to do the conversion.

Comment: how to cast my objects..? when i already know each type... like Double[,]???

Comment: Every introductory C# book covers casting from `object`. You don't need to ask a question here for that.

Answer (score -1):

```
var arr1 = (double[,])result[0];
var arr2 = (double[])result[1];
var arr3 = (double[])result[2];
var arr4 = (byte[,,])result[3];
```

this is the answer... now i know how to cast hahaha!